# Can not save image name while image name has `+` symbol using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I need one help.i need to save one image name inside database which contains `+` sysmbol in its name but after saving its creating `space` at the place of `+`. I am explaining below the image name.

`fmfvweoujrm_G+G image` is the image i need to store into data database but after storing i found `fmfvweoujrm_G G image.jpg` inside database.I am explaining the code below.

```
$image=$_POST['image'];
$sql=mysqli_query($connect,'INSERT INTO db_restaurant_basic (date,image) values ("'.$date.'","'.$image.'",)');
```

Here i need whatever the original image name that should store inside database.Please help me.

Comment: what is the type of image field in db?

Comment: Use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php): `$image = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['image']);`

Comment: The type of image field in db is varchar.

Comment: @Thamilan : i am using also `mysqli_real_escape_string` but still issue is there.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Check the log or add error function

Comment: @Thamilan :No,i am not getting any error but in my db i am seeing that its replacing space instead of `+` for that i can not display it on my browser again after fetching from DB.

Comment: I think the problem is in POST. it converts that. Are you calling this file using AJAX? If so, use `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112750/discussion-between-subhra-and-thamilan).

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to escape `+` in the database. Instead, most likely, the problem occurs when showing the data from the database.

Check the content of your database if it really contains the blank or the plus character by using `mysql` command line utility or some tool like phpMyAdmin.

If my assumption is true, you are creating an image tag and use the string from the database as the `src` attribute. When the browser reads the attribute, it converts the `+` into the blank.

If so, you need to escape it for the browser when creating the attribute:

```
echo '<img src="' . urlencode($imgage) . '">';
```

Comment: it is storing taking space inside database in the place of `+` sysmbol.How can i resolve that.

Comment: No,its storing inside db taking space also.